# Generate date format in javascript with locale appended

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

A 3rd API([mediamath](https://mediamath.api-docs.io/v2/campaigns/),FYI) is requiring the following date format to set the date to `21 march EST` :

> 2019-03-21T00:00:00+America/New_York

How can I generate this string directly using the javascript date object?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to generate that date string based on the current local time and time zone? Or is it based on some other input?

Comment: Current local time and time zone . I want to set the end_date to month end 11.59pm EST and start date to current time and date EST.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate `moment`'s

```
moment().format(moment.HTML5_FMT.DATETIME_LOCAL) // 2019-03-14T22:43
```

and

```
moment.tz.guess() // Asia/Yerevan
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the **moment** and **moment-timezone** libraries, here is some sample code that will take your input and calculate the desired output.

```
let moment = require('moment-timezone');  

let rawInput = "2019-03-21T00:00:00+America/New_York";       
let separatorIndex = rawInput.indexOf("+");
let time = rawInput.substring(0, separatorIndex);
let zone = rawInput.substring(separatorIndex + 1);
let calculatedMoment = moment.tz(time, zone);
let yourOutput = calculatedMoment.format("DD MMM z");

//yourOutput now has "21 march EDT"
```

Reference: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones

Comment: my input will be in local time zone , the output needs to be in EST.